# related to eigen value eigen function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, eigenfunctions

$\frac{d}{dx}(x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{λ}{x}y)=0$ where $λ>0$

Find the eigen  value and eigen function using  the condtion $y(0)+y_1(0)=0$  and $y(1)+y_1(1)=0$

May be it is easy, I try this but did not understand how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your D.E. will be $$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\lambda}{x^2}y=\frac{c}{x}$$, c is constant. Solve this 1st order linear D.E. using Integrating Factor method and try to find the condition so that the D.E. doesn't have a trivial solution.

Comment: If you don't mind can you give me the solution, please?  @user446080